# Typescript/Angular/ESlint: no-unused-vars for constructor params

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have the following code snippet on my typescript class from angular project (v13):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from 'service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent {
   constructor(
       private myService: MyService  
   ) {}

   getUsers() {
      this.myService.getUsers().subscribe(response => {
      // do something;
      })
  }
}
```

I run the project with ESlint version 7.26.0 and extended the following plugins:

```
"plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
"plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
"eslint:recommended"
```

the lint error I got when running ng lint is:

```
'mySerive' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
```

Obviously, myService is being used on my class.

Is that an expected behaviour or how to fix this issue?

PS: I don't want to disable the rule.

Comment: aren't u getting `Constructor implementation is missing.` ? Is it just the typo while copy pasting the code?

Comment: yes it is a typo while copy pasting the code. sorry! fixed now

Comment: It's complaining because you define the parameter in the constructor but never use it. You should either "use" it or disable the rule.

Comment: @youdateme OP is using it , Have a look at `getUsers()` method

Comment: Not in the *constructor*, which is why it's complaining... Example: `constructor(unused) { }`

Comment: but that's the way how the injectable services are supposed to be used in angular.

Comment: @youdateme https://kendaleiv.com/typescript-constructor-assignment-public-and-private-keywords/

Comment: TypeScript offers special syntax for turning a constructor parameter into a class property with the same name and value. These are called parameter properties and are created by prefixing a constructor argument with one of the visibility modifiers public, private, protected, or readonly. The resulting field gets those modifier(s) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: `'mySerive' is defined but never used no-unused-vars` ? is it a typo?

Comment: Yes I know, but ESLint believes it is not being used... because the parameter is nowhere to be found in the source of the constructor. ESLint does not compile your TypeScript, analyze the JavaScript, and report lints from the output. It lints your source code.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801008/eslint-angular-no-unused-vars-hits-type-definition

Comment: thanks @Vikas for the link. solved by adding  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended" to the ESlint config extends.

Comment: According to the accepted answer, the reason seems to be: the "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended" line overrides the "eslint:recommended" rules that won't work with TypeScript, especially the no-unused-vars one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by adding "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended" plugin to the ESlint config.

Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368341/17825554